# AWS cloud root password suddenly not working any more, can I get detailed logs? Have I been compromised?

Tags: amazon-web-services, password

I don't have any indication that I have been hacked, but after a few days without logging in to AWS console I found my AWS console root password didn't work any more. I changed it with reset password, and I have access again. But how could this have happened?

Can I see logs to find out all such password changes?

Comment: Could it have been changed on another AWS property? AWS training, Amazon.com, something like that? It's a long shot, but worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) configured you can check all the logins and password changes there.

Hope that helps :)